# Car mobile charging point fuse

Tags: toyota, battery

I have a Toyota Etios Liva Viera Limited Edition, about 2 years old.

My problem is that, I cannot drive. Now, the drivers which are coming, have found our car a free mobile charging point. My car doesn't go for long drives, only short ones in the city. I am in no mood to allow the drivers charge all their mobiles from the charging point. Many even bring three or more phones to charge! It's getting on my nerves, and I want to stop it.

I want to know if there is a **separate fuse** for this charging point inside the car fuse box. If so, then I can take off the fuse so that the drivers can't charge any more.

If this fuse is not present, is it possible to build one from outside? I don't want to take my car to any local service centre, but only to the company one. I don't know if they will do this innovation. I actually do not want to disable that point completely, because I may, in future, go for long drives or use a vaccum cleaner from that point.

If no external secret switch can be fitted or if no fuse is already present in the fuse box, then I will go to the service centre and ask them to remove the connection from inside. When I'll learn driving, I'll again fit it, so that I can use it again.

I tried checking in Google, but as I'm a layman (my car knowledge, extending from starting the engine to clutch, break, etc, is from the manual given with cars), I couldn't understand anything from the wiring diagrams. I don't even know if any of them suits my car.

I live in Kolkata, India.

My car absolutely looks like this (though this is not my car):

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your charging point? also most modern cars comes with usb input in audio player, if you have one then your driver can still charge his phones out of that port

Comment: For God's sake, the drivers don't have that amount of intelligence till now. I'll send a pic this afternoon.

Comment: Presumably the drivers are employed by you so you can instruct them not to charge their phones?  What is the issue with them charging their phones anyway?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fuse for this - it may also be linked to the interior light for example.
Usually the legend (list of fuses and what they control) is in the lid of the fusebox and / or in the owners manual. (sorry I don't have chance to find it at the moment.)

Comment: I'll try to find it. I don't care for interior light. I'll take off that fuse.